# Impersonate para Cuentas sin contraseñas asignadas

Tags: c#, windows-forms, windows

Estoy utilizando impersonate ya que necesito acceder a cuentas de windows en mi equipo,ya tengo un metodo que funciona perfecto pero solo con cuentas de windows que tengan una contraseña, pero el problema es que no se como hacer para acceder a las cuentas que no tengan una contraseña asignada, osea esas que uno ingresa sin credencial ? como puedo hacerlo ? , mi codigo .....

```
public static extern int LogonUser(
        string lpszUserName,
        String lpszDomain,
        String lpszPassword,
        int dwLogonType,
        int dwLogonProvider,
        ref IntPtr phToken);

public static bool Impersonate(string logon, string password, string domain)
    {
        WindowsIdentity tempWindowsIdentity;
        IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero;
        IntPtr tokenDuplicate = IntPtr.Zero;

        if (LogonUser(logon, domain, password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
                LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref token) != 0)
        {

            if (DuplicateToken(token, 2, ref tokenDuplicate) != 0)
            {
                tempWindowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(tokenDuplicate);
                impersonationContext = tempWindowsIdentity.Impersonate();
                if (null != impersonationContext) return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Agradezco si me pudiesen ayudar,

Gracias.

Comment: Si no hay contraseñas asignadas entonces puedes acceder sin impersonalizacion. O no?